# Is it possible to show the buttons toolbar for Messenger Platform API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I am working on a [Messenger Platform](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform) bot and after reading the documentation and playing around with the API, I have noticed that the Messenger app on the phone isn't showing the toolbar by default as with any other user:

[image]

Is it possible to enable it somehow?

Comment: It seems like there is no such an option to programmatically enable it, but it gets appeared when a user clicks on the area though.